# URL for the apps registered on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, url

I have an iPhone app that supports Facebook login. So I registered it on Facebook. Now I wonder how could I find out the full url for the app on Facebook? I digged around a bit, didn't have luck.

Comment: Are you looking for canvas url (it will be in App on Facebook section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit https://developers.facebook.com/apps

If you have registered your app with Facebook, It will be there with all its information including URL, and public and private keys.